# AngularJS ui-router, add from modal in state

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, angular-ui-router, modalviewcontroller

My app uses `_ui-router_` with a nested state that opens a modal or displays a form to add a `row` in a `table` of the parent state. The modal is opened and his controller receives all events so that it can close the modal.
But now when the user saves I would like to update the `table`. I can see some patterns  like relying on *AngularJs digester* to update the `table` when I insert a `row` in that model that I can use from the parent scope. Or emitting events `$scope`. But I would like to do it the *Angular way*.

What is the favorite pattern to update a state view from a nested state ?